# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\gradle-7.5-bin\gradle-7.5\lib\gradle-launcher-7.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 7.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB
```

[object heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcBk1.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very common problem with many different solutions. As some of them can be difficult to implement, I think the easiest is to add to your
**System Variables** this:

variable name: **_JAVA_OPTIONS**

variable value: **-Xmx1024M**

hope it will help

Comment: Thanks I already solve that..its causing from my system environment..